# Visual Studio - Running datadriven test sequentially in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm working on automating some tests in Visual Studio. However, the different testmethods are dependent on eachother, so always need to be executed sequentially. This isn't much of a problem, unless I'm using datadriven testmethods.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[Datarow("Row1")]
[Datarow("Row2")]
public void DoThisFirst(){
//test execution
}

[DataTestMethod]
[Datarow("Row1")]
[Datarow("Row2")]
public void DoThisSecond(){
//test execution
}
```

I want the tests to run in the following order:

- DoThisFirst - Row1
- DothisSecond - Row1
- DoThisFirst - Row2
- DoThisSecond - Row2

Instead it just runs all iterations of the first method after each other, and next all iterations of the second method.

I've already noticed these methods don't show up in an ordered test, so I'm using a playlist file instead. But there doesn't seem to be a way to specify anything other than the order the methods are executed in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving what you want is as follows.

Have one data driven test method that calls the other two. Add a new column to the data file to specify which test to run. Duplicate each line on the data file and add the two test specifications to each line. In outline the code would be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TheTest()
{
    switch ( DataSource["TestToRun"] )
    {
        case "DoThisFirst" : DoThisFirst(); break;
        case "DoThisSecond" : DoThisSecond(); break;
        default: Assert.Fail("Unknown test."); break;
    }
}
```

The test data, as a CSV, might be:

```
TestToRun,UserName,Password,Etc1,Etc2
DoThisFirst,Row1User,Row1Passowrd,Row1Etc1,Row1Etc1
DoThisSecond,Row1User,Row1Passowrd,Row1Etc1,Row1Etc1
DoThisFirst,Row2User,Row2Passowrd,Row2Etc1,Row2Etc1
DoThisSecond,Row2User,Row2Passowrd,Row2Etc1,Row2Etc1
```

Duplicating the data rows is annoying, but if `TheTest` were modified to just call `DoThisFirst()` followed by `DoThisSecond()` then if `DoThisFirst()` failed then `DoThisSecond()` would not be called. However, given that the two tests must be run in that order it might not be sensible to run `DoThisSecond()` if `DoThisFirst()` fails.

Comment: I didn't end up using this exactly, but you certainly put me on the right path. Instead of having a bunch of testmethods al depending on eachother I went with one DataTestmethod calling a bunch of normal methods and asserting the returns. This will even make it easier to create new testcases that reuse some of the same code. Thx!